# Why does ant.bat not return an error status when run programmatically?

Tags: java, ant, exec, fork

When I run ant from the command-line, if I get a failure, I get a non-zero exit status ($? on UNIX, %ERRORLEVEL% on Windows).  But we have a Java program which is running ant (through ProcessBuilder), and when ant fails, on Windows we cannot get the exit status.

I just verified this with this simple ant test file:

```
<project name="x" default="a">
  <target name="a">
    <fail/>
  </target>
</project>
```

On UNIX, running ant prints a failure message, and echoing $? afterward prints 1.
On Windows, running ant or ant.bat prints a failure message, and echoing %ERRORLEVEL% afterward prints 1.

Now, using the test program below:
On UNIX, java Run ant prints a failure message, and echoing $? afterward prints 1.
On Windows, java Run ant can't find a program named ant to run, but java Run ant.bat prints a failure message, yet echoing %ERRORLEVEL% afterward prints **0**.  What gives?

We're relying on being able to check the exit status after running ant.  We were, anyway.  Why can't we rely on this, programmatically?

Test program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Run {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    Process p = pb.start();
    ProcThread stdout = new ProcThread(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
    ProcThread stderr = new ProcThread(p.getErrorStream(), System.err);
    stdout.start();
    stderr.start();
    int errorLevel = p.waitFor();
    stdout.join();
    stderr.join();
    IOException outE = stdout.getException();
    if (outE != null)
      throw(outE);
    IOException errE = stdout.getException();
    if (errE != null)
      throw(errE);
    System.exit(errorLevel);
  }

  static class ProcThread extends Thread {
    BufferedReader input;
    PrintStream out;
    IOException ex;

    ProcThread(InputStream is, PrintStream out) {
      input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      String line;
      try {
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
          out.println(line);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        setException(e);
      }
    }

    private void setException(IOException e) {
      this.ex = e;
    }

    public IOException getException() {
      return ex;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by creating a *single* batch file (quite a bit nicer than the above but still mysterious):

Content of file `myant.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem RunAnt simply calls ant -- correctly returns errorlevel for callers
call ant.bat %*
```

crucially, without any code whatsoever after the `call`.

Comment: +1 Had the same problem trying to call ant from psake. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating two extra batch files (not very nice, but it works):

Content of file `myant.bat`:

```
call ant2.bat %*
```

Content of file `ant2.bat`:

```
call ant.bat %*
if errorlevel 1 (goto ERROR_EXIT)
exit /B 0
:ERROR_EXIT
exit /B 1
```

Now I can call `myant.bat` as a `Process` from java and I get the correct exit value.

Sorry, I cannot say *why* this works. It's simply the result of a many many tries.

Answer (score 2):

A quick patch is adding the following at the end of ANT.BAT file:

```
exit /b %ANT_ERROR%
```

This problem has long existed and fixed recently.  Refer to [Bug 41039](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41039).

It should be ready in ANT release 1.8.2 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue - if you call ANT within a BAT file and you are interested in saving the errorlevel value, you must keep the call out of an if/else block.

For example, this won't work (...in the middle of some routine):

```
if "%DUMP_ARGS%"=="no" (
   call ant %ANT_TARGETS%
   set ANT_RETURN=%errorlevel%
)
```

You must break out the call as follows (...placed outside that routine):

```
:call_ant
call ant %ANT_TARGETS%
set ANT_RETURN=%errorlevel%
goto :eof
```

(...in the middle of some routine)

```
if "%DUMP_ARGS%"=="no" (
    call :call_ant
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to run Ant via its .bat file? It's just a java program, you could just execute in inside the VM by directly instantiating and executing the Ant runtime. Have a look inside ant.bat, see what its Main class is, and execute it directly.

Comment: ant.bat is complex and running the java program directly is correspondingly complex.  I'm seeing the same problem executing ant.bat from within an ant script (no, don't ask).  I cannot see the ant.bat errorlevel.  I don't want to deliver ant2.bat to my builder's environment, but I will if I have to.

Does anyone know *why* this works?

PS: What is the formatting markup for this comment???

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-standing issue for older versions of Ant on Windows. I believe it has been fixed in version 1.7.0.

See [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13655) for details and [this discussion](http://www.nabble.com/Failed-taskdef-reporting-as-successful-build-td13303352.html) for an approach to address it.

Comment: I'm on ant 1.7.1.  I just tried running with the full path to make sure I'm not running another version of ant.  Same behavior: correct error level when run from a prompt; incorrect errorlevel when run from a program.

Answer (score 0):

I googled to this thread and find tangens' answer almost solved my problem: the exit coded are always 0 on Windows from `ant.bat`, even when I intentionally failed an ant build; I need to get the exit code from a TFS build script, and it showed that even the `%ERRORLEVEL%` can't be found in TFS build.

However, I have to remove the `/B` from `exit` lines, otherwise, it still always shows me exit code 0.

Answer (score 0):

i solved replacing `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` with `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0`:

```
call ant

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :build_error
```