# How to use sshexec task to call another ant and get expected result?

Tags: ant, ssh

Here is the scenario :

An ant script is launched on computer1, logged on computer2 using sshexec ant task to call a shell script that calls itself another ant script.

The main script looks like

```
<target ...>
  <sshexec host="*" username="*" password="*" command="someShellScript.sh" />
</target>
```

The remote script is basic :

```
#!/bin/sh
setting some env vars
ant buildfile.xml
```

All scripts are correctly executed, but when the remote build fails, the main Ant script return BUILD SUCCESSFUL instead of FAILED.

I guess it uses the result of the sh script.

Is there a way to get the second Ant script result ? But maybe, there is a better way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answering :

it comes from a bug in ant.bat

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456979/why-does-ant-bat-not-return-an-error-status-when-run-programmatically)